# Android: Class Not Found runtime exception - release build only

Tags: android, android-activity, runtime, release, classnotfoundexception

We have an app that has had several version on Google Play and has been working fine.  The latest updated causes a runtime error "Class not found" for our main activity.  The activity is called 'Home'.

The runtime error does NOT occur on a debug build, only as release build.

The activity has not changed for several updates, but suddenly has started raising these runtime errors on start-up.

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: One of the first things we tried, Gogu :) Nope, not a problem.

Comment: Managed to fix it after a lot of head-scratching - very easy in the end. All we had to do was 'clean' before the release build. That should have been step one!

Answer (score 0):

Try **do a clean on your project** and export of **ECLIPSE** 
This way: project > android tools > export as signed application package.